# Disconnecting view from business logic. Who creates new views?

Tags: oop

Form1 gets a request to perform some action.  Form1 sends the request to my business logic class.  If there's some error in the request,  a notification is sent back to View1 and he presents an error message.   If there is no error in the request,  a new view must be created.

Who creates the new Form?  Do I notify Form1 and have him create Form2?  Does the business logic class call the Form2 constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Model View Controller (MVC) design pattern the **controller** would create the new **view**.  Using this paradigm the **controller** would receive the request from the **view** (i.e. Form1) and send it to the correct **model** (i.e. business logic class).  Depending upon the results from the  **model** the **controller** would either send a message back to Form1 or create a new **view** in Form2.  This is a cleaner separation of concerns.